# Vertical align DIVs

Tags: css, html, templates

Suppose I have 2 DIVs , one on top of each other.

How do I align the text of the top one to the TOP , and align the text of the bottom one to Bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True -- vertical-align only works if you set the `display` of each div to `table-cell`

```
div#top, div#bottom { display: table-cell }
div#top { vertical-align: top }
div#bottom { vertical-align: bottom }
```

Comment: note that table-cell isn't support in IE7 and under :( (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html for more info)

Comment: What about Webkit, in browsers?

Answer (score 0):

**[This is how you can do it.](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)**

**Demos:**

http://www.emblematiq.com/blog/vertical_align_with_css/assets/02.html

http://www.emblematiq.com/blog/vertical_align_with_css/assets/03.html